# is it possible to animate date or time picker to a particular time

Tags: android-layout, android-animation, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

currently i am working on `Date picker` and `time picker`, so one required comes out is that is it possible to animate(roll) `date picker` or `time picker` to a particular time as i am not able to find this on `stackoverflow` 
is there something we can do in `OnTimeChangedListener` or `OnDateChangedListener` to achieve this

```
OnDateChangedListener mdatechange=new OnDateChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Logic for Animation
    }
};
```

or if its possible with `XML`
please guide me

Comment: did u get solution for this.Actually i have to do same thing.if you can help me then plz